# Deploying React app fails due to dependencies after upgrading React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

After upgrading React to v18 I am facing issues deploying it. I did everything as described in the docs, searched boards and kept trying changing stuff to get the deployment working again, but it doesn't.

I get the following errors:

```
$ npm i
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
npm WARN Found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@6.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm WARN   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^6.2.1" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
npm WARN   eslint-plugin-jest@"^25.3.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
npm WARN node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm WARN   peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
npm WARN     eslint-plugin-jest@"^25.3.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm WARN     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"^5.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         dev react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (ts-api-utils, tsutils)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   dev react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     dev react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
```

Any idea why that happens?

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "webapp-pwa",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.14.0",
        "npm": ">=8.5.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.7.17",
        "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^4.0.1",
        "@capacitor/android": "^5.2.2",
        "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.6",
        "@capacitor/core": "^5.2.2",
        "@capacitor/filesystem": "^5.1.1",
        "@capacitor/geolocation": "^5.0.6",
        "@capacitor/ios": "^5.2.2",
        "@capacitor/share": "^5.0.6",
        "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.6",
        "@capawesome/capacitor-screen-orientation": "^5.0.0",
        "@date-io/moment": "^2.17.0",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@fontsource/inter": "^5.0.5",
        "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
        "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.95",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.3",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
        "@sentry/capacitor": "^0.12.2",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.1.1",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.54.2",
        "apollo-upload-client": "^17.0.0",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001518",
        "capacitor-ios-autofill-save-password": "^1.1.5",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "gleap": "^11.0.8",
        "i18next": "^23.4.1",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "node": "^19.8.1",
        "pulltorefreshjs": "^0.1.22",
        "qr-scanner": "^1.4.2",
        "query-string": "^8.1.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
        "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
        "react-player": "^2.12.0",
        "react-qrcode-logo": "^2.9.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
        "react-swipeable": "^7.0.1",
        "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
        "swiper": "^10.1.0",
        "victory": "^36.6.11",
        "yup": "^1.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@capacitor/cli": "^5.2.2",
        "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-document-nodes": "^4.0.1",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.0.1",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.3.7",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers": "^4.0.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.2.0",
        "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^17.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.196",
        "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
        "@types/pulltorefreshjs": "^0.1.5",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.3.1",
        "@types/victory": "^35.0.0",
        "@types/yup": "^0.32.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint": "^8.46.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.3",
        "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
        "npm-check-updates": "^16.10.17",
        "prettier": "^3.0.0",
        "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6"
    }
}
```

Comment: The error _says_ why. You need to resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the errors you pasted complain about your version of TypeScript. I suggest downgrading your TypeScript to version 4. One way to do it is to change the line:

```
"typescript": "^5.1.6"
```

to

```
"typescript": "^4.0.0"
```

After doing that, please delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** and run:

```
npm install
```

I assume this might solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it might be an issue with the ESLint dependency version. Try running `npm install eslint@latest eslint-config-next@latest`

If that doesn't work, try uninstalling all the deps and rerunning `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround is to change your package.json file.
I got the below error ! and I solved it by adding the overrides.

---

`resolve npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1 npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.2.2 npm ERR! node_modules/typescript npm ERR! dev typescript@"^5.2.2"`

---

add overrides section into your package.json and then run
`npm install`

```
  "overrides": {
        "typescript": "^5.2.2" // in your case you need to use 5.1.6
      },
```

For further info you can take help from the below reference link:
[Typescript issue git hub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080)